# How to include/exclude source files from the project depending on the build configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to include a file in the project only under the 'Debug' build configuration and not in the 'Release' build. How can I do that via the IDE?

I am already able to achieve the above by manually editing the '**.vcxproj* ' file.

> ```
> <ClCompile Include="..\..\..\..\dbg_helper.c" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'"/>
> ```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop (Version 12.0.21005.1 REL).

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the IDE. There is an infinite set of things you can only do via editing project file.

Comment: I agree with Simon, but, possibly you could make the code be excluded via using C directives;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx
Might be a bit messy, but in theory it would perform what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to exclude it from the build and not from the entire project tree, you can do it from UI.

Just edit the file properties.

[image: file properties] [image: file properties]

Now, you can change to the desired configuration, for which you want to edit its properties.
[image] [image]

Exclude your file for all configurations and platforms.
[image]
And then include it only for the configuration you want it to build.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

*Unloading the project and edit the file by hand* is technically done through the IDE, so I guess that you are looking for way to do this through the Project Properties, which is **not possible**.

In C# you can decorate your class with *ConditionalAttribute* like so:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")] // or another constant you use in your configurations
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

And the similar for C++:

```
#if DEBUG // or another constant you use in your configurations
...
#endif
```

I would however not recommend using this too much as you can run into problems.